# Which Constructor takes precedence when there are two matches for a Generic Class's Constructor

Tags: c#, generics, overloading, constructor-overloading

What determines which constructor is used if a Generic class has 2 constructors:
One takes `(T data)`, and another `(string errorMessage)`.

And an instance is created with type string?

For me it seems to be using the constructor with parameter `(string errorMessage)` instead of `(T data)`.

- I'm wondering why?
- And is there a way to make it use the generic `(T data)` constructor instead?

Luckily I don't need to in my case, but I don't know how I would.

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public GenericClass(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public GenericClass(string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

New instance is created with either:

```
new GenericClass<string>("some error");
```

Or:

```
new GenericClass<string>("some data");
```

I thought it would give an Ambiguous Constructor error, but it doesn't.
It always uses the `(string errorMessage)` constructor.

Comment: I'm guessing theres a rule where static typed constructor parameters always take precedence over matching dynamic ones.
If anyone knows for sure, let me know, thanks!

Comment: So, but what exactly is your question? Why does C# work like this?

Comment: Question is why does it use the (string errorMessage) constructor?
Is there a precedence rule?
Also: how would I make it run the (T data) constructor if I needed it to?

Comment: If you want to enforce to call the other ctor then use this: new GenericClass<string>(data: "some data");

Comment: Brilliant that works thanks a mill!
If you wanna make a proper answer you can and I'll accept.
Where in the docs can that be found? I couldn't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not specific to constructors. The same behaviour can be observed in case of method overloading. For example:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public static void MethodA<T>(T data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic version has been called");
    }

    public static void MethodA(string errorMessage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("String version has been called");
    }
}
```

The related documentation can be found here: [Overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1164-overload-resolution).

---

You can enforce the call of the other constructor if you are taking advantage of [named parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) feature of C#:

```
new GenericClass<string>(data: "some data");
```

---

Of course this technique works only if the parameter names are different.
So, this won't work if you would define your class like this:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public GenericClass(T _)
      => Data = _;

    public GenericClass(string _)
      => ErrorMessage = _;
}
```

A solution could be for this problem

- introduce factory methods
- change the properties' `set` to `init`
- and create a `private ctor`

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    public T Data { get; init; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; init; }

    public static GenericClass<T> CreateWithData(T _)
      => new GenericClass<T> { Data = _ };
     
    public static GenericClass<string> CreateWithError(string _)
      => new GenericClass<string> { ErrorMessage = _ };
     
    private GenericClass() {}
}
```

---

**UPDATE #1** It is not related to the OP's question.

Last night I have received the [Pundit badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit?userid=13268855) and I was a bit surprised.

I've proposed a solution in a comment then I've left a post with a more detailed description (as the OP asked).

My comment had only a single upvote at the time when I posted my answer. At the time of this update it has 5 upvotes.

Why? I mean, why do people prefer to upvote a comment instead of an answer? I think I will never understand how SO members are thinking ...

Most probably I should do a mind-shift and don't give a damn. I should be happy about the fact the OP got his answer.

</ventilation_of_my_feelings>

Comment: You have linked to the VB docs...

Comment: @DavidG Oops, let me fix it :D

Comment: Perfect answer @PeterCsala thanks so much!
I've been using C# for years and never saw anyone use the named parameters functionality before :P

Comment: @FeargalKavanagh I've just updated my post with an alternative solution if you want to avoid the usage of named parameters.